# How can i put a XML view in an array variable?

Tags: java, android

i am creating a CAROUSEL view, that can be swipe left or right, but the problem that i am having is, i have 5 images and 1 XML view to be need to put in the carousel function, the 5 images is already working but for the last bullet in the carousel a view should be loaded on it, and it can still be swipe if they want to go back to the 5th images or to the first image.

here is the code:

```
public class AboutHelp extends AppCompatActivity {

    CarouselView carouselView;
    int[] sampleImages = {R.drawable.help_1, R.drawable.help_2, R.drawable.help_3, R.drawable.help_4, R.drawable.help_5,R.layout.activity_send_feed_back};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_help);
        androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        // add back arrow to toolbar
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
        carouselView = findViewById(R.id.aboutCarouselHelp);
        carouselView.setPageCount(sampleImages.length);
        carouselView.setImageListener(imageListener);

    }

    ImageListener imageListener = new ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void setImageForPosition(int position, ImageView imageView) {
            imageView.setImageResource(sampleImages[position]);

        }
    };
```

is this possible? can i load an XML to the last bullet? any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ViewListener instead of ImageListener. Try this

```
carouselView.setViewListener(viewListener);
```

```
    ViewListener viewListener = new ViewListener() {

        @Override
        public View setViewForPosition(int position) {
            if (position < 5) {
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(AboutHelp.this);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  //setting image position
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setImageResource(sampleImages[position]);
                return imageView;
            } else {
                View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(sampleImages[5], null);
                return customView;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: hi sir, what is the mContext, where should i declare this. thank you sir.

Comment: oh thank you sir, i used getApplicationContext instead of mContext, thank you very much sir.

Comment: You should using AboutHelp.this instead of applicationContext